# MVC3 DropDownList - no validation if only 1 item displayed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a list of items I am displaying in a dropdown....when I use the code below in the view with a (htmlattribute size = "4")

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedOptions, new SelectList(Model.Options, "Id", "Value", Model.SelectedOptions), new { size = "4", style = "width: 160px" }) 
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => Model.SelectedOptions)
```

the validation works...ie the whole list is highlighted in red and the validation error message is displayed.

However, when I use this line below (htmlattribute size = "1")

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedOptions, new SelectList(Model.Options, "Id", "Value", Model.SelectedOptions), new { size = "1", style = "width: 160px" }) 
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => Model.SelectedOptions)
```

the validation does not work and the post action is triggered in the controller.

Any ideas how I can get the validatioin to work with just a single item displayed at any one time like a dropdown?

Comment: Could you show your `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` on the `Model.SelectedOptions` property?

Comment: Sure                                                            [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must select at least one of the options.")]                                                    public IEnumerable<int> SelectedOptions { get; set; }

Comment: Try changing `SelectedOptions` in your model in to a `String` - or whatever data type describes it best. In other words, get rid of the enumerable definition. I suspect that {Size = 1} is expecting a non enumerable value to get/set from the model.